# Input Blur returning Null

Tags: jquery

Here I use input text for user, issue is that before user enters data the `attr()` function get null value from the text input element

The Code is For User Validation their input

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("User input=" + name);
    $("input").blur(function () {
      var name = $(this).attr('userinput');
      $("#info").load("try1.php", {
        userinput: name
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Suggest you edit the question title to be succinct and to the point.

Comment: what are you trying to do here `var name = $(this).attr('userinput');` ? is it correct ? the way you are doing. ad you should provide the HTML code of the form or the input that you are using this script with

Comment: var name=$(this).attr('userinput'); stores the value enter by user in text box.Is that True??